# Воспроизведение видео с удаленного ресурса по ссылке

Tags: c#, .net, vlc

Ищу возможность воспроизвести файл, находящийся на удаленном сервере, при этом сделать возможной буферизацию этого видео-файла.
Воспроизвести его не проблема, а вот управлять буферизацией я так и не научился.

Исходные данные для проигрывания ссылка типа: http://somesite.com/video_file.mp4

**Пробовал:**

- MediaElement WPF
- ActiveX vlc plugin - нет там гибких настроек по буферизации
- libVLC.dll - к сожалению библиотеку VLC не получается правильно
  подтянуть в проект, русскоязычных мануалов совсем нет, а варианты
  на инглише постоянно ругаются на то, что нужных функций в библиотеке
  попросту нет.

С помощью чего именно можно реализовать затею?

Answer (score -1):

Есть библиотеки:

- http://directshownet.sourceforge.net
- http://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com/

Есть платные библиотеки поддерживающие онлайн проигрывание в WPF:

- http://www.leadtools.com/sdk/multimedia-suite.htm#-
- http://www.visioforge.com/video-capture-sdk-net2.html or http://www.visioforge.com/media-player-sdk-net.html

Нарыл еще вот этот код для directshownet:

```
        var fGraph = new FilterGraph() as IFilterGraph2;
        var cGraph = new CaptureGraphBuilder2() as ICaptureGraphBuilder2;
        cGraph.SetFiltergraph(fGraph);

        IBaseFilter sourceFilter = null;

        hr = fGraph.AddSourceFilter(@"http://localhost:8080/tempStreaming.asf", "SourceFilter", out sourceFilter);//ВОТ ЭТА СТРОКА
        DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

        var vRender = new VideoRenderer() as IBaseFilter;
        var aRender = new AudioRender() as IBaseFilter;

        hr = fGraph.AddFilter(vRender, "vRenderer");
        DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

        hr = cGraph.RenderStream(null, MediaType.Video, sourceFilter, null, vRender);
        DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

        hr = fGraph.AddFilter(aRender, "aRenderer");
        DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

        hr = cGraph.RenderStream(null, MediaType.Audio, sourceFilter, null, aRender);
        DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

        var mcx = fGraph as IMediaControl;
        hr = mcx.Run();
        DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
```

Взято с: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7487900/4423545

---

Как отдельный вариант: можно тупо в апликуху встроить браузер, в нее засунуть код видеоплеера и внутри него уже реализовать открытие файла с интернета :) Странный ход, но сработает :)